# How to limit the number of network calls in a for loop?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire

I have some objects on the server for each user and I have to fetch them all. I, first, get the objects count from the server to calculate the number of network calls I have to make in batches of 30. Lets say if there are 2000 objects then the number of calls I have to make is 2000/30 = 67. I set the offset = 0 and the limit = 29 for the first call and then increment both the offset and limit by 30 and make the second call and so on. The problem is that if I send more than 8 calls simultaneously in a for loop then the calls start failing and even if I retry its keeps on failing. I'm using Alamofire to send post requests to the server. I've noticed that if I send 8 requests in parallel everything seems fine. How can I ensure to make 8 calls in parallel and when all 8 are complete, send another 8 to the server.

Here is the piece of code:

```
 let count = Double(totalTransactionsCount)
  //The maximum amount of transactions to fetch in one call.
  //let maxLimit = 30
  let calls = Int(ceil(count/Double(maxLimit)))

 for call in 1...calls {
        print("Calling call \(call) with offset:\(offset) to limit:\(limit)")
        callFetchTransactionWith(offset, limit)

        offset += maxLimit
        limit += maxLimit
    }


 fileprivate func callFetchTransactionWith(_ offset: Int, _ limit: Int, _ callCountPercentage: Double, _ calls: Int) {
    TransactionsModel.reportTransactions(offset: offset, limit: limit ,success: { (transactions) in
        ACTIVITYCALL += 1
        self.currentSyncingProgress = self.currentSyncingProgress + CGFloat(callCountPercentage)
        Utility.logger(log: "\(self.currentSyncingProgress)", message: "Activity Increment Progress")
        if ACTIVITYCALL == calls {
            TransactionsModel.assignSequenceNumbers()
            self.didCompleteProgressAndSync(duration: 2.0)
            return
        } else {
            self.updateProgressBar(value: self.currentSyncingProgress)
        }
    }, failure: { (response, statusCode) in
        print(response,statusCode)
        self.callFetchTransactionWith(offset, limit, callCountPercentage, calls)
    })
}


static func reportTransactions(offset:Int,limit:Int,
    success:@escaping ( _ model: [TransactionsModel] ) -> Void,
    failure:@escaping APIClient.FailureHandler) {

    let params:Parameters = [
        "offset":offset,
        "limit":limit
    ]

    let headers:[String:String] = [
        "X-Auth-Token":Singleton.shared.token
    ]

    if !Connectivity.isConnectedToInternet {
        Constants.UIWindow?.showErrorHud(text: AppString.internetUnreachable)
        return
    }

    APIClient.shared().requestPost(endpoint: Route.reportTransactions, params: params, headers: headers, success: { (response) in
        guard
            let data = response as? [String:Any],
            let transactions = data["transactions"] as? [[String : Any]]
            else {return}

        let transactionModels = Mapper<TransactionsModel>().mapArray(JSONArray: transactions)
        TransactionsModel.save(transactions: transactionModels)

        success(transactionModels)
    }) { (response, status) in
        print(response,status)
        failure(response,status)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

### Semaphores

This looks like a good use case for semaphores.

[image]
*Credits: https://unsplash.com/photos/5F04PN6oWeM*

Let me show you how to do it with Playground so you can run this solution locally and then import it into your project.

### Playground

First of all create a new empty Playground page and these 3 lines in order to import the required libraries and enable concurrency.

```
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

> Once you decide to move this solution to your project you need only the `import Foundation` line.

### Contants

Now let's define the following 3 constants.

**Concurrent Calls**
This is the number of concurrent calls you want to perform.

```
let concurrentCalls = 8
```

**Semaphore**
This semaphore will allow no more than 8 threads to be executed. When the 9th thread asks for access it is put in wait until one of the 8 threads running finishes.

```
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: concurrentCalls)
```

**Background queue**
We will use this queue to dispatch asynchronously all the calls.

```
let backgroundQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "Background queue")
```

### fetchData(completion:

This function is an emulation of your remote API call. It just waits for 3 seconds and then calls the completion passing the "" string which represents the result.

```
func fetchData(completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3.0) {
        completion("")
    }
}
```

### fetchAll(completion:)

And now we are at the core of the solution.

```
func fetchAll(completion: @escaping ([String]) -> Void) {
    // 1
    let storageQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "Serial queue")

    var results = [String]()
    let totalNumberOrCalls = 20

    for i in 0..<totalNumberOrCalls {
        backgroundQueue.async {
            semaphore.wait()
            fetchData { result in
                storageQueue.async {
                    results.append(result)
                    if i == totalNumberOrCalls - 1 {
                        completion(results)
                    }
                }
                // 2
                semaphore.signal()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### How does it work?

We have a Semaphore with a value set to 8.

Everytime we want to perform a network call, we ask the semaphore if we can start calling

```
// 1
semaphore.wait()
```

If the semaphore holds a value **grater than 0**, then it **allows** our remote call and decrements its value.

Otherwise if the semaphore **holds 0** then the network call is **not executed**, it is instead put on **wait** until one of the previous calls ends.

As soon as a network calls ends we call

```
// 2
semaphore.signal
```

This way the semaphore value is **increased by 1** and does allow another waiting call to be executed.

### Test

Now we call call

```
fetchAll { results in
    print(results)
}
```

There will no more that 8 concurrent calls to `fetchData` and as soon as all the calls are completed the result will be printed

```
["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
```

### Conclusion

Hope this helps, if you want more details have a look this answer where I talk about semaphores https://stackoverflow.com/a/51816661/1761687

Comment: `if i == totalNumberOrCalls - 1` . The given result might be the wrong one, since it could be a very short task compared to the others, it will be executed before the others would be finished (unless Semaphore's value is 1). To prevent that you have to make a counter of executed tasks, and when that `counter == totalNumberOfCalls - 1`, only then we reach the final one